# Laravel function to add a supplier, and associated addresses and contacts

Tags: php, mvc, laravel, repository

I have a function `addSupplier()` that adds a supplier. Each supplier has multiple addresses and each address has multiple contacts.

```
public function addSupplier ($request) {
        // ADDING THE SUPPLIER BASIC INFO
        $supplier_fillable_values = array_merge(
            $request -> except('address_contact_inputs'),
            ['created_by' => $this->getAuthUserId()]
        );
        $new_supplier = Supplier::create($supplier_fillable_values);

        // ADDING THE SUPPLIER ADDRESSES AND THE ADDRESS CONTACTS
        foreach ($request -> address_contact_inputs as $address) {
            // ADD ADDRESS
            $new_supplier_address = $new_supplier -> addresses() -> create([
                'address'       => $address['address'],
                'created_by'    => $this -> getAuthUserId()
            ]);

            // ADD ADDRESS CONTACTS
            foreach ($address['contacts'] as $contact)
                $new_supplier_address -> contacts() -> create([
                    'name'          => $contact['name'],
                    'phone_number'  => $contact['phone_number'],
                    'created_by'    => $this -> getAuthUserId()
                ]);
        }


        return $request -> address_contact_inputs;
    }
```

Everything works fine but question is: Is this the best practice or I should use events and create an event for:

1. Storing the supplier basic info
2. Storing the supplier addresses
3. Storing contact for each supplier's address

Answer (score 1):

You could use events for triggering these kinds of things, but there is a danger that your code starts to become harder to follow. Martin Fowler gives a good top-level talk on it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STKCRSUsyP0).

There are two issues jumping out at me:

Firstly, your method accepts a request object so there is no indication as to what the requirements of that method are. You could change the method to accept specific arguments such as $created_by, $address_details, etc. This would make it easier to re-use the code elsewhere if needed.

I would make the controller then responsible for preparing that set of data (e.g. handling the preparation of the address details array, getting the 'created_by' etc). And make your addSupplier method work with a set of arguments that could be run from anywhere in your app.

```
public function addSupplier ($primary_contact_details, $contact_addresses, $created_by = NULL) {
    // ADDING THE SUPPLIER BASIC INFO
    $supplier_fillable_values = array_merge(
        $primary_contact_details,
        ['created_by' => $created_by]
    );
    $new_supplier = Supplier::create($supplier_fillable_values);

    // ADDING THE SUPPLIER ADDRESSES AND THE ADDRESS CONTACTS
    foreach ($contact_addresses as $address) {
        // ADD ADDRESS
        $new_supplier_address = $new_supplier -> addresses() -> create([
            'address'       => $address['address'],
            'created_by'    => $this -> getAuthUserId()
        ]);

        // ADD ADDRESS CONTACTS
        foreach ($address['contacts'] as $contact)
            $new_supplier_address -> contacts() -> create([
                'name'          => $contact['name'],
                'phone_number'  => $contact['phone_number'],
                'created_by'    => $this -> getAuthUserId()
            ]);
    }

    return $request -> address_contact_inputs;
}
```

Secondly, it's good practise to avoid too many levels of indention, so you could  refactor to use one level of indentation and splitting out the foreach loops to their own public/private methods on the same class.